# What is the right way of simplifying this trigonometric expression and why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fractions

Problem: $$\frac{\frac{cosA}{sinA}-cosA}{\frac{cosA}{sinA}+cosA}$$

sol1:$$=\frac{cosA\left(\frac{1}{sinA}-1\right)}{cosA\left(\frac{1}{sinA}+1\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{sinA}-1\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{sinA}+1\right)}$$
$$=\frac{cosecA-1}{cosecA+1}$$

sol2: $$=\frac{cosA-sinAcosA}{cosA+sinAcosA}$$
$$By ÷cosA$$
$$=\frac{1-cosecA}{1+cosecA}$$

Which is the right answer and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last step is incorrect.

$$\dfrac{1-\sin A}{1+\sin A}=\dfrac{\csc A-1}{\csc A+1}$$

Comment: How? Can u b little specific

Comment: @vidyakumargv $$\sin x =\frac{1}{\csc x}$$

Comment: OMG such a big mistake I did not notice.. thank u guys

Comment: I would regard the LHS as simpler than the RHS, if only because it involves $\sin A$ rather than $\csc A$.

Answer (score 0):

your sol2 should be:

## $$=\frac{cosA−sinAcosA}{cosA+sinAcosA}$$

dividing by cosA gives,

## $$=\frac{\frac{cosA}{cosA}-\frac{sinACosA}{cosA}}{\frac{cosA}{cosA}+\frac{sinAcosA}{cosA}}$$

the result is ,

## $$=\frac{1-sinA}{1+sinA}$$

focus on your mistake.